# How to specify an Interface for an argument when another argument is a specific value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have following...

```js
interface Group {
    name: string
    isPublic: boolean
}

interface User {
    id: string
    age: number
}

type EntityType = 'group' | 'user'

function doStuff(type: EntityType, entity: Group | User): boolean {
    if (type === 'group') {
        return entity.isPublic
    }

    if (type === 'user') {
        return entity.age > 18
    }

}
```

I want to ensure that when the first argument is `group`, the `entity` argument interface is `Group`... I believe I need to use Generics, but I cannot work out for the life of me the proper syntax.

How do say "When `type` is value X then `entity` uses interface Y?

TIA

Edit: Updated to a MRE.

Comment: You could use a *destructured discriminated union* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5AEMN) (it would be nice if you either defined `groupStuff` and `userStuff` or just left it out, so that your code is a valid [mre]).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867871/how-to-specify-an-interface-for-an-argument-when-another-argument-is-a-specific#comment133822850_75867871) Similarly to jcalz, but more "dynamic": https://tsplay.dev/ND85lN

Comment: Both excellent and have absolutely solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: So @vr. do you want to write up an answer or shall I?

Comment: I think you already have enough on your plate @jcalz , so if you'll allow it, I could write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to tell TypeScript somehow that the two parameters are related. Currently, all your code has is two unions, that have no relation to one another.

One way you could add a correlation is to use a discriminated union of tuples, whose first element can be used as the discriminator. Then, you can destructure the tuple in the parameter list:

```
function doStuff(...[type, entity]: ["group", Group] | ["user", User]) {
```

This [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQPYFcAOyDeAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpwdAClgEYAbYAlp8MGARDgh2AX0KFQkWIhQBVOtAIcSwACa0GTEGx3I4zGmSwU+0OQrABPHCgCi4YM4AqLlAF5kACJmTFwg5AAfYKxNKCD2QhgsEAQwYAwQZD0MAGUwLBgYAAoAOnKAbWdXABpkCE9nAF1aCpCwnCC69GwcJqjkNtjoLuQNaCaASm1SZGAYZGLqgP9A9t6g6aJZ2dDe-MKShvTnSfZZ+TN5xeXkVbXh+K2zWceDouLjryczs3lLvQQBACOBQFDJVLpTLIPa4d4lWE4Wg9XCTWgANww+nYgOBoPBKTSGSybwKH0etHGUDRyEx2MIQA), but what if you have more than two choices? You can express this union of tuples more succinctly as a map of strings to their respective interfaces:

```
interface EntityMap {
    group: Group;
    user: User;
}

type EntityType = keyof EntityMap; // define EntityType as a key of the map instead
```

You can then map over each entity type and retrieve the corresponding interface type from the map:

```
function doStuff(...[type, entity]: { [K in EntityType]: [K, EntityMap[K]] }[EntityType]) {
```

This produces the same type as before, but now you can easily add more members to the union if you wish:

[image]

If you're concerned about readability, you can always extract this into its own type alias:

```
type Stuffs = { [K in EntityType]: [K, EntityMap[K]] }[EntityType];

function doStuff(...[type, entity]: Stuffs) {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQPYFcAOyDeAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpwdAClgEYAbYAlp8MGARDgh2AX0KFQkWIhQBVOtAIcSwACa0GTEGx3I4zGmSwU+0OQqXR4SZAFFwwMAE8AsnDwiUmRmTFxadGwcdmCsTShaDXtCeUIfHBQPMC9vABVvDOQAXmQAawhvDBh3Tx9-aIV0lABlMCwYGDpigmQAbQBpZFAa7J98jIBdWgGAGhGc+oGJieRZXqyc8YgJ9kIYLBAEbIwQZD0MVvaYAAoAOnveprmIWu8p5EuOugBKbWDgarXJrFIolABEoSiYN+QWCpEhuE+Nxeo283xipFS-0BwNB4Li0GhfzhJAJUCR1xROXRZnkqT0EAQAjgUBQ+0Ox1OCJwFO5ETCOG+tAAbhh9OwGUyWWyDkdgCdkGSKWTEvEhchReLCEA)