# TS function parameter type based on another parameter

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

#### I am doing a chrome extension, and trying to inject code to the page but, i don't know how to do this without setting `fun: any` and `arg: any`

```js
type funs = typeof getPageInfo | typeof setPercen;

async function injectScriptToPage<K extends funs>(fun: K, arg: Parameters<K>): Promise<dataPageU> {
    if (actTab.id === undefined) {
        console.log("vacio tab id");
        return;
    }
    const pr = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: actTab.id},
        // files: ["./dist/injectScript.js"],
        func: fun, // <- Error here
        args: arg,
    });
    const x = pr?.[0]?.result as dataPageU;
    if (x === undefined) {
        console.log("vacio result");
        return;
    }
    if (!("titulo" in x) && !("currentTime" in x)) console.log("Err no es ni refresh ni once");
    return x;
}
```

Functions:

```js
export function setPercen(l: StateVideoI[]): void
```

```js
export function getPageInfo(once: boolean, YoT: "Y" | "T"): dataPage
```

[Error on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnAtx.png)

The code works using any, but i want to use type if is posible

Comment: You would need to use a discriminated union like [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867871/how-to-specify-an-interface-for-an-argument-when-another-argument-is-a-specific/75869842#75869842).

Answer (score 0):

When you use generics with functions typescript allows you to pass fewer parameters than the generic signature. ex: type A <F extends (b: string)=> void, let you pass ()=> void to F. Maybe you do not have to use type parameters and instead use injectScriptToPage(fun: typeof getPageInfo | typeof setPercen, arg: Parameters | Parameters).